# Calculate y2 given x1, y1, x2 and angle

Tags: trigonometry, angle

I'm a bit confused and haven't used trigonometry in years, in the following image I have the x1, y1 and x2 coordinates and I need to calculate the y2 value. Given the angle in degrees I first convert it in radians and then use tangent to calculate the y2 value, however the result is not the one expected.

This is what I did:

```
x1 = 91
y1 = 32
x2 = 100
angle = 19

angleRad = angle * π / 180
y2 = y1 + (x2 - x1) * tan(angleRad);
```

Any suggestion to where I may be wrong?
[image]

Comment: In your drawing, you have $\alpha$ as the angle to the vertical. But in that case the correct result is $\displaystyle \tan\alpha = \frac{\text{opp}}{\text{adj}}=\frac{x_2-x_1}{y_2-y_1}$, hence $$y_2=y_1+(x_2-x_1)/\tan\alpha=y_1+(x_2-x_1)\tan(90^\circ-\alpha).$$ So that's the first thing to check. (The other point to make sure of is that your tangent function actually does take radian arguments.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to start from the definition:
\begin{align}
\tan(19°)
&=\frac{\textrm{Length of side opposite to the angle}}{\textrm{Length of side adjacent to the angle}}\\
&=\frac{x_{2}-x_{1}}{y_{2}-y_{1}}
\end{align}
and there you can identify your mistake. It doesn't matter if you use degrees or radians as long as you use the appropiate version of $\tan(\theta)$ in your machine or app for calculation.